# I have made a script for automation for web scraping to download cvs

Tags: memory-leaks

In that script while using headless mode I am facing issues that after downloading each file its getting replaced with existing one. Even I have added in the script that it will rename each file after downloading it but its not working? What should i do to fix this?

how to fix my code?

```
        # Generating a unique filename with a sequence number
        while os.path.exists(os.path.join(download_path, f"{first_file_name}")) or \
                os.path.exists(os.path.join(download_path, f"{first_file_name} ({sequence_number})")):
            sequence_number += 1

        download_filename = f"{first_file_name}.csv" if sequence_number == 1 else f"{first_file_name} ({sequence_number}).csv"
        prefs = {
            'download.default_directory': download_path,
            'download.prompt_for_download': False,
            'download.directory_upgrade': True,
            'download.default_filename': download_filename
        }
        options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
        
        time.sleep(10)
```